# Oracle XMLDB Registering XML Schema

Tags: oracle, xsd

Hello I have a problem with Oracle XMLDB Express Edition 10g.
I am trying to register a fully valid and working .xsd Schema via 
dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema,
 but keep getting 
ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier
I have tried everything: triplechecked my xsd and query code. 
There were a couple of topics on Oracle forums but there were no answers.
Please help.
Here is my code:

```
 begin
dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(
 'opta',  
 '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/opta/" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/opta/">
    <xs:element name="Document">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Order" type="tns:Order" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="Order">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Products" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Product" type="tns:Product" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Client" type="tns:Client" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Product">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="Producer" type="tns:Producer"/>
            <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Producer">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Organization" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Client">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Organization" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

');
end;
```

Comment: Looks like a version issue to me. What version are you using?

Comment: The problem was solved by trying executing this in a console instead of web interface.